# Formatting scanners and random generators

Tags: java, random, int, java.util.scanner

```
Random deck = new Random();
int cardtype = deck.next(52)+1;
```

I have an "error: next(int) has protected access in Random" on the period in the second line, I've used code with random generators before but haven't ran into this problem yet, any suggestions?
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    placeholder = scanner.nextInt;
the same type of situations is going on in this piece too, but with a scanner. I believe the problem is similar for both, I think this would be a quick fix if I knew how to do it right, suggestions?

Comment: You're probably looking for `deck.nextInt(52)`.

Comment: the reason I had +1 on deck,nextInt(52) was because I wanted the range to be from 1 to 52, not 0 to 52. Do you know of a way that i can exclude te 0 from the range?

Comment: There's no problem with `+1`, you're just calling the wrong method.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it, should probably be:

```
Random deck = new Random();
int cardtype = deck.nextInt(52)+1;
```